# What is the ideal measure of reliability when each subject only responds to a subset of items?

Tags: r, missing-data, reliability, cronbachs-alpha

Lets say I have a measure with 40 items, but each subject only responded to 20 of them. Is there a way to still calculate reliability in R?

I've looked into Robust Cronbach's Alpha using the "coefficientalpha" package, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Cronbach's alpha is based on the correlation / covariance matrix of the items. You should be able to calculate that with pairwise deletion, and then calculate alpha (assuming your data are missing completely at random).

You could do something more sophisticated like multiple imputation or maximum likelihood estimation of the covariance matrix, but I don't think this is necessary.

The psych::alpha() function will calculate this.